# Is there a way to know when a FusionChart is ready for export?

Tags: javascript, export, fusioncharts

I have a FusionChart that I can successfully export from using exportAtClient='0' and exportAction='download'. However, my application needs to be notified when this export process completes. Is there a JS callback that I can use to be notified when the export is fully captured?

The closest I've seen so far is [FC_ExportReady](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/powercharts/Contents/Export/ECClientCallback.html), but I can't seem to get it to work, despite the fact that the documentation claims it will work for server-side export and download (yes, I know it says PowerCharts, but I have tried this with PowerCharts as well). Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FC_ExportReady is raised when individual charts in the queue have finished capture process and have passed their data to Export Component.

You can check out a sample using the below link:
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/Code/ExportChartSamples/BatchExport/Callback.html

Comment: This only works with batch exporting, if I understand the documentation correctly. What about browsers that don't have flash, on which I can't use the batch export component? How do I do this in those cases?

Comment: Batch export component is not supported for JavaScript charts. As a suggestion, to export the entire web page along with charts, please refer to following blog post: http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2013/03/how-to-save-charts-as-images-at-server-side/

Comment: All of this does require additional server-side setup. Are there any plans to make this a first-class feature of the FusionCharts API?